# How can I find the web host company for a web domain?

Tags: web-hosting

A bunch of people and I have been using a web board for several decades.

The admin for that web board is missing in action.

I would like to contact the web hosting company that hosts that site and web board to ask them to do some critical things.

I have a linux box and the web.  How can I use whois and other tools to find the web host for that web site?

Comment: “I would like to contact the web hosting company that hosts that site and web board to ask them to do some critical things.” – That’s just not going to happen.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your specific whois question: You can go to a site like lookup.icann.org and enter the name of the website. For example if you enter poleguy.com in the search, you'll see the nameservers are pointing to awsdns, which indicates that the hosting company is amazon. Which will help you track down who to get in contact with.

Go to the registrar and/or hosting providers websites and enter service tickets.

If you cannot prove that you have a legal right to claim ownership and the official owner is unresponsive, the registrar and hosting provider are unlikely to do anything for you. Unless maybe you are trying to remove illegal content, etc.

As an example, I recently had something like that happen to me with my kids school who lost an administrator and all of the passwords went with him.

If the owner is truly MIA, like the admin for our school, you will have to ask the registrar and/or hosting provider to reset the password and take control of the domain. It may involve you proving that you are the owner of the domain, which for a school might not be too hard, but might be much harder for other types of domains without association with established non-web presence to verify against.

As an example: In an email from namecheap.com they said:

> Namecheap will comply with any valid U.S. court order and/or subpoena. If you are able to provide us with a court order demonstrating you have rights to this domain, we will gladly help you to sort things out.
>
> Thank you for understanding.
>
> ---
>
> Regards,
>
> Nataly Kl.
>   RM Representative
>
> Risk Management Department (Risk&Abuse)
>
> Namecheap, Inc."

This also matches their policy of complying with court orders:
https://www.namecheap.com/legal/general/court-order-and-subpoena-policy/

Comment: “If the owner is truly MIA, [...] you will have to ask them to reset the password and take control of the domain.” – That is not going to happen. In your example, the admin was never the owner of the domain in the first place. This is not at all comparable to OP’s case.

Comment: @Daniel B, no, in my example the admin was the owner of the domain under his own name. That's why, when he left, the school had no access to the domain, and had to recover the domain ownership by putting in a service ticket and convincing the registrar to reset the password and allow the school to take control. I'll edit my answer to be more clear.

Comment: Okay, taking your advice the nameservers are  NS63.DOMAINCONTROL.COM

NS64.DOMAINCONTROL.COM.  Whois shows one set of info, Googling people say it is GoDaddy.com.  How do I know which?

Comment: @user787832, You didn't need to google it, you could plug domaincontrol.com back into lookup.icann.org and it will list domaincontrol.com as belonging to go daddy. You now need to go ask go daddy if they can take care of your problem. Again, if you're not the owner they are not supposed to help you without a court order or the equivalent. I'm happy to answer more questions, but if you feel my answer helped with your initial question, can you mark it as accepted? I'm trying to break 200 points. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, if you are not the owner of the site - as in paying for it - there is nothing you can accomplish.  Domain registrars and web hosting companies are not going to hand over personal contact information, nor will they change anything or give you access to the website.

Comment: As a follow up, what you claim is not strictly true. They say they won't give anyone access, and they shouldn't give anyone access, but in the case I described in my answer the principal of the school called namecheap and they reset the password for her.